# Alexa Custom Skill execute action a scheduled time

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I want to make my custom skill able to execute some actions at scheduled time.

The flow will be like *"Alexa, do something at 3 PM"* and Alexa executes the requested action at PM.

My problem is that I don't understand which interface / directive I need to use.

Has anyone done it?

Answer (score 0):

Routines sound like a good use case for you and you have a couple of options to integrate with them.

1. If your skill is live, you should be able to go into the Alexa App and under Routines, select Skills as an action and then select your skill. This will launch your skill whenever your configured trigger occurs. If you want to deep link into a certain experience in your skill, you'll need to add a custom task, certify your skill with this update, then select your new task as the action in your Routine. More on that here: https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/integrate-custom-task-with-alexa-routines.html
2. There's a new feature you can sign up to use called Alexa Routines Kit which will allow your skill to enable Routines for users by voice: https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/get-deeper/alexaroutineskit